# Create a list of all lists in an array with Java streams

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-stream

I have an array of `Node` which all have a list of `Variable`:

```
Node[] arguments; // argument[i].vars() returns List<Variable>
```

I would like to create a list which contains all the variables. I do it like this today:

```
List<Variable> allVars = new ArrayList<>();
for (Node arg : arguments) {
    allVars.addAll(arg.vars());
}
```

Can I do the same thing using streams?

I have tried this but it returns me a `List<List<Variable>>`, whereas I would like a `List<Variable>` with all the list's elements appended (using `addAll`):

```
List<List<Variable>> vars = Arrays.asList(arguments).stream()
                                  .map(Node::vars)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can also use `Stream.of(arguments)` instead of `Arrays.asList(arguments).stream()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to convert the `Stream<List<Variable>>` to `Stream<Variable>` before calling `collect`:

```
List<Variable> vars = Arrays.asList(arguments).stream()
                            .map(Node::vars)
                            .flatMap(List::stream)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```